# Doctrine creating useless join table

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

so, i have two entities: `Genre` and `Game`

**Genre.php**

```
<?php

namespace Acme\Bundle\DemoBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * Genre
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="genre")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Genre
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=64, nullable=false)
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="display", type="string", length=64, nullable=false)
     */
    protected $display;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="text", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $description;

    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection|Game[]
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Game", inversedBy="genres", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    protected $games;

    // ... Irrelevant Constructor and following getters/setters
}
```

**Game.php**

```
<?php

namespace Acme\Bundle\DemoBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * Game
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="game")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Game
{

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=256, nullable=false)
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="display", type="string", length=256, nullable=false)
     */
    protected $display;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="text", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $description;

    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection|Genre[]
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Genre", inversedBy="games", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="genre_game",
     *    joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="genre_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *    inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="game_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     *    )
     */
    protected $genres;

    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection|Platform[]
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Platform", inversedBy="games", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="platform_game",
     *    joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="platform_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *    inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="game_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     *    )
     */
    protected $platforms;

    /**
     * @var Image[]
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Image",mappedBy="game_id", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    protected $images;
}
```

When i run `php app/console doctrine:schema:create` or `update`, it creates all of the needed join tables I specified above, but it also creates **`genre_genre`**

This table is always empty, and doesnt seem to do anything, and prevents me from running `php app/console doctrine:schema:update`'s later, and its trying to add an index to it that already exists

Anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Game->genres and Genre-game are inversed by each other, which is invalid - one needs to be owning. I believe there is a doctine:schema:validate command you would find useful

Comment: yupppp. that tool was actually pretty helpful, thanks

Comment: @Jessica, you should make an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Game->genres and Genre-game are inversed by each other, which is invalid - one needs to be owning. I believe there is a doctine:schema:validate command you would find useful.

Answer (score 0):

Sir, I think you have made many to many relation(bidirectional) in those mapping classes. According to [doctrine documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-unidirectional) that will create that table for relation of those `Game` and `Genre` like in the example.

You can create the db table then create the mapper class to verify with [generate-entities](https://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/tools.html?highlight=command%20line#entity-generation). This way you can verify the schema and the mapping.

Comment: i know its supposed to make genre_game and the like, but it was making genre_genre

Comment: can you make the tables and reverse engineer the problem? I meant (by http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/tools.html#reverse-engineering) you make the tables first then then the php classes? Also for many to many mapping I think Unidirectional  referencing may be better.

Comment: Figured it out using @Jessica's tip